# How to add a soecific label to a class by using spring data neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

The spring data neo4j can put a "Person" into neo4j with two labels `("Person", "_Person")`.

How can I change it to `com.xxxx.xxxx.Person`?

Are there two classes named Person in different packages?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This looks like a valid question to me. The edit also seems  incorrect on the final sentence.

Comment: @JohnMark13 it is probably because you didn't do any research and as the answer also cites from the manual.

Comment: @UmairAhmed I think that the question touches on a slightly oblique facet of SDN and despite simply citing a section of the the manual in my answer I do not think that RTFM would have helped the OP at all. You could probably answer most questions on SO with a downvote or a RTFM if you fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly buried towards the end of the documentation you will find [Section 20.15 Entity Type Representation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#reference_programming-model_typerepresentationstrategy).

> As some type information is also stored in labels, node/relationship-properties and/or indexes it might amount to a substantial amount of data in the graph. It is possible to use an @TypeAlias("name") annotation on nodes and relationships to have a short constant name for each type which is (unlike the default approach) renaming-refactoring-safe. From 3.0 onwards, **Spring Data Neo4j uses the simple class name** as the default whilst previous versions used to default to the fully qualified name. If you would like to use the **fully qualified class name by default**, you can
>
> - Register a Neo4jMappingContext bean configured with an instance of org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.ClassNameAlias
> - Override the spring "entityAlias" bean with an instance of org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.ClassNameAlias. For example, using XML config this would look as follows:
>   `<bean id="entityAlias" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.ClassNameAlias" />`

As to why you want two different classes named Person in your domain, that's another question...

Comment: Great!You solve my problem. My question looks like a XY problem but your answer is quite comprehensively And @TypeAlias("name") is what I want. Thanks. I use spring data neo4j and want batch import data in neo4j db. but it seems that the spring doesn't use the "xxxx/db/data/batch". Now I change to load CSV files. but that means I need to generate the csv by myself(then I focus on how spring enerate the data including labels). Do you know any good solution about the batch import?

Comment: @JiangYuan I'm afraid that as yet I have no experience of the batch importer but start a new SO question and I'm sure someone can help.